# How do I automatically italicise text in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

How do I automatically italicise text in Microsoft Word 2007 in a way that is font agnostic (preferably as I type)?

E.g: I want "in situ" (in any font) to change automatically to "*in situ*" (in the same font).

Currently, I can use AutoCorrect, but it converts back to the same font as the one in which I first told it to autocorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't duplicate your problem for some reason. But here's how I managed to get the results you want.

*Note: Step 2 is important.*

1. Type *in situ* anywhere on your document.
2. Highlight it then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to italicize it.
3. **With the italic text selected**, open the Autocorrect Options window (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>).
4. Under the AutoCorrect tab, select **Formatted text**. Type "in situ" under **Replace**. (see image below)
5. Click **Add** then **OK**. *Note: Don't forget to click Add*

[image]

Comment: It works! I have no idea what I did differently using your technique vs what I did, but it works. Ta!

Answer (score 2):

You can add an underscore before and after the text to auto-format it as italics.

E.g.

```
_in situ_
```

Note that this may be disabled by default. Check Proofing options to enable.

Instructions on how to get to the option can be found here: [Use automatic formatting as you type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-automatic-formatting-as-you-type-HP010082297.aspx#BM1).

Answer (score -1):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
2. Type the text in *Find What*.

   [image]
3. Click in the *Replace With* text box.
4. Press *"More>>"* Options to open.

   [image]
5. Inside *More>>* options choose *Format* drop down menu.

   [image]
6. Select *Font dialog*.
7. Choose font style as italic.
8. Finally click on *Replace all*.